# SQLite database when updating the app on the store

Tags: ios, sqlite, app-store, updates

I'm using sqlite in my iOS app, my database file is called data.db.
Let's suppose that I have only one table in it and i push the app to the AppStore.
In the next version I updated the data.db and added an other table and push the app to the AppStore.
So the questions are, the user who has the old version and update the app, will he have the new data.db with the 2 tables? Or does he keep the old data.db? 
If he keep the old one, how can update his data.db programmatically? And if he will get the new one so it can be a bad idea if i will store his personnal data in the data.db.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you distribute an app with a database, that database is stored in the bundle. If the user needs to update the database, the app cannot programmatically update the file in the bundle, so you generally copy the database from the bundle to the Documents folder (if you haven't already done so), and then the app can update that Documents version with new information from the user.

When you distribute updates of the app, the file in the bundle is replaced/updated, but the user's copy in the Documents folder stays there unless you explicitly remove it programmatically (or the user manually uninstalls the app). So, using your example, the database in the bundle will have the two tables (but without the user's data), and the copy in the Documents folder will have only one table (but with the user's data).

If you want a single database with the two tables, but also with the user's data, you'll have to copy the new, two table database to the Documents folder and then update this version with the user data from the old Documents database. Or alternatively, you might include a script that alters the user's database so it now includes both tables (e.g. does the necessary ALTER TABLE and CREATE TABLE).

As an aside, it's useful to keep track of what version a database is, either by including a "configuration" table that holds this information, or by availing yourself of the `user_version` or `schema_version` pragmas. That way you can programmatically inspect the database and determine what course of action you might need to take.

Comment: Thanks that was useful.
And in my case I  will not save personal data of the user, so the best is to overwrite the old database and let the user use my new two table database.
So I don't have to do any special thing, I'll just update my database manually and let it updated by the app.